# How would I perform octal arithmetic using integer variable?

Tags: c, integer, octal

Say I want to add two octal values, `0144` to `0144`, in C.

```
int a = 0144;
int b = 0144;
int result = a + b;
printf("%d, %o", result, result);
> 200, 310
```

In my program, a hex value is entered, this is converted to a octal value, but the conversion leaves the result looking like an integer in base 10 rather than base 8.

For example:

```
int oct = convertHexToOct(64)
printf("%d, %o", oct, oct);
> 144, 220
int result = oct + oct;
printf("%d, %o, result, result);
> 288, 440
```

So the decimal representation of the oct variable is really the octal value of the desired integer. This means any arithmetic done to with this variable will be done in base 10, which is not what I want to do.

What I basically would want to do, ideally, is something like

```
int intAsOct = "0" + oct;
int octalResult = intAsOct + intAsOct;
```

But this obviously will not work. So the root of the question is, how do I treat an integer variable that was saved without the leading 0 as an octal for use in arithmetic?

Comment: Integers stored in memory are usually stored as binary values. It's only during input or output that conversion to octal, decimal, hexadecimal, ... , is involved. One alternative would be to use an array of characters, where each character contained a digit, but you'd then have to create functions for basic math using these arrays.

Comment: Yeah, I've considered that but I'm trying to avoid a bunch of extra work rather than embrace it. So there's no way to 're-input' a variable and prepend a 0 so that the value is treated as an octal when converted to binary?

Comment: "Treated as an octal when converted to binary" makes no sense. When it's converted to binary, it'll be treated as binary. Octal and binary are just two different ways of representing the same numbers, arithmetic doesn't work differently between them. It's not at all clear what you're trying to accomplish, here.

Comment: Okay, lets see if I can phrase this differently. How do I take a base10 integer, "144" and have C treat it as a base8 integer, "0144", so that I can preform arithmetic on the later?

Comment: @TimCarlson: Suppose you have a function to do this. What do you want to happen if you feed it, say, the base10 integer "999"?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths This would never be the case, as the values are from a function "convertHexToOct" that will never output a number with digits > 7 because it properly converts hex values to octal values. The issue is that the returned value is equivalent to "144" rather than "0144"

Comment: @TimCarlson: OK, I still think the problem is rather obviously with your `convertHexToOct()` function in the first place, but since you don't show it, see my answer for how to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your comment:

> How do I take a base10 integer, "144" and have C treat it as a base8
>   integer, "0144"

you can do it manually, but the easiest way is to convert it via the standard library string functions, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int dec_to_oct(const int dec)
{
    char buffer[64];
    char * endptr;

    /*  Convert number to decimal string representation  */

    sprintf(buffer, "%d", dec);

    /*  Convert decimal string representation back as octal  */

    long l = strtol(buffer, &endptr, 8);
    if ( *endptr != '\0' ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error! Could not convert decimal %d to octal.\n", dec);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return (int) l;
}

int main(void)
{
    int num = 144;
    printf("Before conversion: %d, %#o, %#x\n", num, num, num);

    num = dec_to_oct(num);

    printf("After conversion: %d, %#o, %#x\n", num, num, num);

    dec_to_oct(999);    /*  This will fail  */

    return 0;
}
```

with output:

```
Paul@Pauls-iMac:~/Documents/src/sandbox$ ./dec_to_oct
Before conversion: 144, 0220, 0x90
After conversion: 100, 0144, 0x64
Error! Could not convert decimal 999 to octal.
Paul@Pauls-iMac:~/Documents/src/sandbox$
```

Comment: Paul, thank you very much for taking the time to answer this question. strtol is the function I was looking for but could not find.